# Getting "servo jitter" when trying to move Actuonix actuator slowly. Works fine when going from 1-2 ms in RC protocol

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, servo

I have a PQ12-30-6-r Actuonix actuator that's moving erratically. When I set the width of the pulse from 1-2 ms then it will move down immediately, and vice versa back up. I can go to 1.5 ms as well, or 1.7, and it will move there immediately.
The counter period I made for the pulse using my STM32 MCU and timer is 10k giving me a decent resolution for the width of the pulse between 500 and 850 (clock speed 72 MHz with a prescaler of 144 to bring the timer frequency to 500 kHz).
When I set the width of the pulse using my MCU incrementing or decrementing by 1 every 20 ms then the motion is not actually smooth. Slower, yes, but definitely not smooth. It jumps at certain parts.

I verified using my scope that the signal was increasing or decreasing smoothly, and it is. I noticed the servo motor is 5 V logic level so I got a logic level converter out and verified it's stepping up the voltage on the signal, and it is.

I have some videos but I am not sure how to attach them here. I hope the information I have provided will shed some light on the situation, though.

I played around with the timing setting on the mcu to increase the delay between pulse changes, and this resulted in it moving smaller movements, but still at the same real time interval.

Comment: Have you read the datasheet what to do if servo motion seems erratic?

Comment: Yes, it suggested to add a 1-4ohm resistor in series with the voltage input. I don't have a resistor that low, so I used a 20ohm resistor. It didn't change the behaviour at all.

Comment: You can either create a gif from the videos and embed them or (easier, I think, given size limits etc.) upload them to someplace like Youtube and add links.  How often are you sending the pulses (i.e. what is the space between rising edges of the pulses)

Comment: I am sending the pulses every 20ms (should I use the format "20 ms" over "20ms" here?). I verified this on my scope not long ago just as a sanity check.

Comment: I’ve never met an RC servo with a control system I’ve actually liked - this may end up being the best performance you’re going to get.

Comment: The servo gearbox has some back lash and therefore the position regulator loop often has a dead band. So the target position must have a minimum difference until a move begins and it may overshoot a bit.

Comment: Well I changed the delay between pulse changes to 60ms, the result was that it did do finer movements, but at the exact same real time intervals. This leads me to believe the servo can only read signal changes every 1000ms or something... which is awful. I have now decided to buy a can-stack style actuator which is a unipolar stepper. I just need to find a suitable driver for it. I also did see some circuits for a mosfet driver or something online. I will check that as well. But maybe you have some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The manufacturer emailed me back saying I could increase the frequency to 100Hz or 200Hz. I did that and the behaviour was actually exactly the same. Looks like the can-stack actuator is the way to go.